# C++ LoadLibrary Not working

Tags: c++, string, dll, loadlibrary, tchar

```
if (LoadLibrary(L"d:\\cwebpage.dll"))
       MessageBox(0, L"Loaded", L"ERROR", MB_OK);
else MessageBox(0, L"Error", L"ERROR", MB_OK);
```

Its not working, I have tried

```
if (LoadLibrary(_T("d:\\cwebpage.dll"))) //#include<tchar.h>  

if (LoadLibraryA("d:\\cwebpage.dll"))

if (LoadLibrary("d:\\cwebpage.dll")) //#undef UNICODE
```

Nothing is working

Comment: If the function fails, the return value is NULL. To get extended error information, call GetLastError. Try it and tell us what it shows

Comment: i am new to win32, don't know did correct or not
MessageBox(0,  (LPCTSTR)GetLastError(), L"ERROR", MB_OK);
is showing nothing. Just empty prompt box

Comment: Actually no error, always Else part is executed.

Comment: error C3861: 'sprintf_s': identifier not found

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure the `D:\cwebpage.dll` is exist. As Mike Vine mentioned before, If the function fails, the return value is NULL. To get extended error information, call `GetLastError`.

```
if (LoadLibrary(L"d:\\cwebpage.dll"))
{
       DWORD nErrCode = GetLastError();
       MessageBox(0, L"Loaded", L"ERROR", MB_OK);
}
else MessageBox(0, L"Error", L"ERROR", MB_OK);
```

The detailed information about `nErrCode` is defined at page "http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681381(v=vs.85).aspx".

Function `sprintf_s` is defined in `stdio.h`, in your file that reference `sprintf_s`, add line`#include <stdio.h>`.